# Why use PUT and DELETE when I can do it with POST or GET

Tags: php, json, http, rest

I am going to start using a PHP REST frame work called [Slim](http://docs.slimframework.com/) and there is some documentation about PUT and DELETE so I am wondering if I should bother with it if I can delete a record on my database with a GET or POST just as well.

Are there any advantages?

Comment: It's just about using those request methods for what they were meant for and it makes the request more clear if the method being used partly defines the request itself.

Comment: Well, why bother with GET when you can do everything with POST? : ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

99% convention, but useful convention. It is handy to know what kind of request comes in and makes API usage easier (instead of forcing a dev to remember to add `action=blah`, you can just tell them "whenever you want to delete something - same request, `DELETE` verb).

The 1% remaining is through a simple fact: using `DELETE` avoids having to put an extra parameter in `GET` or `POST` variables to signify a deletion. That's bytes saved through not having to repeat yourself by choosing a field that is modifiable, rather than adding an extra field. There is no point in adding complexity when you can do it without doing so.

Things to look out for also include: idempotency of verbs. This is a convention, however - `GET` should be idempotent as it is easily triggerable through browser requests. It should be "safe to repeat".

(Last useful bit: most MVC frameworks split endpoints by HTTP verb. Saves you an if!)

Comment: Could the downvoter actually say why they've downvoted?

Comment: exactly ,it is all about convention. i don't see any other benefit why we use other http verbs such as put, delete, etc. BTW, as for avoiding an extra parameter that would save us a byte, we could also use a different method "DeleteCustomer" and it accepts http post request with just an id parameter (/customer/delete). So this way we will still save a byte by not specifying action paratmer.

Answer (score 2):

There is little harm in using POST to do a DELETE, except for the fact that it is less obvious to developers and intermediaries cannot see that you are deleting something.

However using GET for a DELETE would be a horrifically bad idea.  The HTTP spec says that a GET operation must be safe and deleting something is not safe.  There are many practical reasons why you should not use GET for delete, a little googling should find plenty of information on this.

Use PUT when its "complete replace" semantics fit your scenario.  Otherwise, don't bother IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

It is used as a way of mapping requests to action, splitting the type of the request as meta information (i.e. `GET`) and the actual data as what being passed in the query/body (as oppsed to sending another query string param that states the action, like `action=delete` or `/delete/` somewhere in the uri.

You've chosen a REST framework, which uses the REST "rules".
Read more about REST - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Comment: All I'm saying, is that the part of REST that defined these GET/POST/PUT/DELETE is a mean of using meta information that exists in the request as the type of the request, as opposed to specifying the type of what you want to do with the information passed via query params or the body of the requests.

Comment: using /foo/12/delete as opposed to object=foo&id=12&action=delete is not relevant - you still used the action in the uri

Comment: "As opposed .." is misleading at best because the query is not *as opposed* to the previous subject.

Comment: I don't see how it's misleading, but whatever - I've added that part, enjoy.